# How to place data from a file with Strings and Ints into an Array / How to compare arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a little confused and am seeking some direction in how to achieve my goal. I want to read a file that has the name of a Mini Golf player, their age, and their scores for 9 holes of playing. I then want to find their par for each hole by using their age. (If it's a younger player the par scores are higher)

My input file is practice.txt with the following content:

**Jay     57   4 3 2 3 5 3 2 3 4**

**Gloria  39   4 4 3 4 3 4 3 3 5**

**Manny   14   5 6 4 6 5 6 4 4 6**

**Joe      3   9 8 8 7 6 6 7 5 7**

The player's age is denoted by the second number (Ex: Manny is 14 years old.)

I placed the par score information into a 2D Array. However, I can't figure out how to compare the 2D Array of numbers with my Array List of Strings? What's a way I can fix this or what is a way of thinking I should have to solve this problem? Here is what I have so far!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class imTryingHere {
 public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {

     int [][] ageGroups = 
    {
       {4},
       {7},
       {11},
       {15},
       {100},
    };

    int[][] holePars=
    {
      {8,8,9,7,5,7,8,5,8},
      {7,7,8,6,5,6,7,5,6},
      {6,5,6,5,4,5,5,4,5},
      {5,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,4},
      {4,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,3},
   };


    // Read in file

    File inputFile = new File ("practice.txt");
    Scanner golfScores = new Scanner (inputFile);

    // Create file into an Array of data. 

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (golfScores.hasNext())
    {
      list.add(golfScores.next());
    }
    System.out.println(list);

  }
}
```

Should I be trying to convert the strings into ints or how can I place the data from the file into an int Array? Or should I not be using an array for the data file at all? I'm up for everything and anything :)

(Note: I'm very new to Java as you can probably tell so please try to use beginner concepts. Also, we haven't learned BufferedReader yet so it is not needed and neither is try catch)

Edit: Ideally I'm looking for a way to place data from a file into an array that has both strings and numbers.

Comment: You can make Strings into ints like this: `int n = Integer.parseInt(s)` if `s` is a String.

Comment: I'd recommend trying a different approach. Using arrays like this will make your code pretty unreadable and confusing. You might consider using `HashMap`s and/or data classes.

Comment: Also, Java is an OO language. You should use objects and classes. Your description of the problem suggests that you should have a List<GolfPlayer> and a List<ParsForAge>.

Comment: How can I parse an entire array of strings? @DUman

Answer (score 0):

A single array cannot contain both strings and numbers.

You could have multiple arrays, one each for the names and ages, and a 2D array for the scores.

Instead of reading a word at a time from the file read a line at a time, then split up the line onto name, age and scores.

Comment: An object array can contain both Integer and String, though

Comment: How would I place the data into three different arrays from reading the file? (One for names, ages, and scores.)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're reading your input one word at a time and you're putting all the words into one array.  I don't understand why you are doing this.

Instead, put them into different arrays, for example, the first value into a name array, the second into an age array, and so on.

```
name[ i ] = golfScores.next();
age[ i] = golfScores.nextInt();
for (j=0; j<9;j++)
    scores[i][j] = golfScores.nextInt();
```